# Remove duplicate rows in mysql, retaining only that with the lowest id

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete all rows with the same values in all columns except `id`, except the row with the lowest `id`.
Given this data:

```
id year file name language download
1  2014  a    x     h        d
2  2014  a    c     i        d
3  2014  a    x     h        d
4  2014  a    x     h        d
5  2015  b    y     j        d
6  2015  b    y     j        d
7  2015  b    y     j        d
```

Here I want to delete 3 and 4 (leaving 1  - the lowest id), and delete 6, 7 (leaving 5).

"Matching" means both rows have the same 'year', 'file', 'name', 'language' and 'download'.

There might be more then 10 duplicate rows. I want to delete all the rows, but keeping the lowest id row.

Comment: yes. keeping the lowest lowest id row

Comment: it will not work...

Comment: Yeah, the `.*` bit was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mysql's multi-table delete syntax with a self-join:

```
delete b
from mytable a, mytable b
where b.year = a.year
and b.file = a.file
and b.name = a.name
and b.language = a.language
and b.download = a.download
and b.id > a.id -- this condition picks the higher id(s) for deletion
```

This should perform quite well, since it's essentially a single join.

Comment: i run the command, but it takes much time. I have a large database of more then two million rows.

Comment: @jaki put an index on whichever non-id column has the most number of different values. If the number of different values is less than about 100, make the index on 2 columns with the second column being the non-id column with the second most number of different values

Comment: i thought of running the code manually one by one, instead of  running all at the same time. If the file is "a", then check and remove all duplicates where file is "a". Where to put the code - "WHERE file=a" in the above code?

Comment: @jaki just add it to the end: `<query in answer> and a.file = 'a'`

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE
  FROM myTable a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.id
               FROM   myTable b
               WHERE  a.year = b.year
                 AND  a.file = b.file
                 AND  a.name = b.name
                 AND  a.language = b.language
                 AND  a.download = b.download
                 AND  a.id > b.id);
```